# WSDL to XML to FLEX Datagrid

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, datagrid, null, wsdl

I have a Webservice set up to reach out to my database and when called upon by a SWF, it returns an XML to populate a Datagrid. It is all working with one exception. Should I not have any data in the table to return, I get an 1088 error stating that the XML is NULL.

What I would like to happen is that the Datagrid would just display an empty grid until there is data to populate it and not receive the error message. This is a display only board like a flight status display at an airport, so there is no user interaction to reset the error messages.

I am using PHP with MySQL and Builder 4.6 if this matters.

Comment: Is your error from your Flex code or from your PHP code?  What is the code that throws the error?

Comment: Found the issue. It was a line that I thought I had removed. Now to figure out how to mark this as solved.

Comment: You have to post an answer to your own question; and then you can mark it as the formal answer. Since you have low rep, there may be a delay before you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a Flash Player [runtime error](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/runtimeErrors.html), as opposed to something generated by PHP: "Error 1088: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed").

If that's the case, just make your server return some valid XML when there are no results: `<root></root>` or `<root><data></data></root>` or something similar.

Perhaps you're already doing something similar to this. If so, you should show what your XML looks like (when there are no results), and how you are consuming the XML on the Flash side (are you using it as the dataProvider to the grid or trying to use an e4x expression on it, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Sunil. I found and Alert code that I thought I had removed from the code. Once I deleted it, the error never appeared again.